# Почему функция _sleep срабатывает раньше чем должна?

Tags: qt, qtcreator, sleep

Здесь я устанавливаю картинку в метку и, в теории, она должна появиться раньше чем за 5 секунд. Но в первую очередь происходит задержка и только потом показывается картинка:

```
void HighLight4::on_go_out_clicked()
{
    QPixmap pict("C:/Users/Meshtli/Desktop/hi/Kursach/other/correct.png");
    ui->cor_photo->setPixmap(pict);
    ui->cor_photo->show();
    _sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Ну так правильно, входим в метод, в нем вначале идет загрузка картинки, потом методом show() вы формирутете в очереди событий указание/событие на то, что надо бы обрисовать метку, потом пауза на 5 сек и только потом прога выходит из данного метода и в цикле событий берется ваше событие на отрисовку вашего лэйбла и соответственно происходит сама отрисовка

Answer (score 0):

Используйте неблокирующий sleep. Пример функции:

```
    void sleep(quint32 ms)
    {
        QTimer timer;
        timer.setInterval(qBound(1, ms, 3600));
        timer.setSingleShot(true);
        QEventLoop loop;
        QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
        timer.start();
        loop.exec();
    }
```

Или можно вызвать QApplication::processEvents() перед _sleep(5000).